# Flipping a file with a constant amount of use of file positioning functions

Tags: c, file, file-io

> Write a function that flips all the bits in a file such that the last bit will be the first, and the first bit will the last and so on.
>
> Note: only a constant amount of use of file positioning functions is allowed (such as `fseek`), i.e, the use of file positioning functions isn't dependent on the size of the file.

We have to flip each byte and each byte in the file. The function that flips a byte is pretty trivial, but I can't think of a way of flipping the bytes in the file without use of `fseek`. I can place the whole file a an array but that doesn't seem right, if the file is huge then it won't work.

Any hints or ideas please?

Comment: So you should, in a way, *reverse* the bits in a file?

Comment: Yes @JoachimPileborg

Comment: You could always read smaller blocks, but it would still make the number of seeks depend on the file-size so it's not an acceptable solution. Is memory-mapping the file okay?

Comment: Does the file fit into memory?

Comment: @joop we can't assume that.

Comment: What do you mean by memory mapping? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: See e.g. [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). For very large files (several gigabytes), it's only realistic to do on 64-bit systems though.

Comment: If it doesn't fit into memory, mmap()ing is probably the cheapest solution. (only two pages at a time will be needed: amount of seeks = amount of reads = amount of blocks in the file)

Comment: By the way, it might be tweaking the rules but there is a way of doing with only two seeks in the source file (to get the input file size), but requires variable number of seeks in the output file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two buffers of size B bytes, and your files is of M*B bytes length. Then, if you can use an auxiliary file, you could use the following algorithm, given in pseudo-code, to solve your problem with a number of `fseek` equal to `0`. Let's call `F1` the original file, and `F2` the auxiliary file, at each iteration the role of the two files is swapped:

```
for (i = 0; i<M; i++) {
  read a block of F1 in buffer1 and flip its bits
  for (j = 0; j < (M-i-1); j++) {
     read a block from F1 in buffer2
     write buffer2 to F2
  }
  write buffer1 to F2
  for (j = (M-i-1); j < M-1; j++) {
    read a block from F1 in buffer2
    write buffer2 to F2
  }
  exchange the role of F1 and F2
}
```

The final result is in `F1`.

The algorithm in practice reverses the bits of each block, and writes it in the "correct" position in the auxiliary file. The number of passes is equal to the number of blocks, so one should have two buffers as large as the memory can afford.

Of course the algorithm is inefficient, since it rewrites the entire file M times, but respects the given assignment.

Comment: It does `M` calls to `fseek()` after each iteration of the outer loop. They can be disguised as a pair of `fclose()`, `fopen()` but they still are pointer repositioning. `M` for `F1` and another `M` for `F2`.

Comment: At each iteration you close the file, then you start reading *sequentially* F1 and writing *sequentially* F2. There is no "positioning" or "repositioning" function involved. `fopen` is not `fseek`, in my opinion, and the substance of the problem was not to "reposition" inside a file.

Comment: The reason the problem asks to use few repositioning (either as `fseek()` or as `fclose()` followed by `fopen()`) is the lag introduced by the mechanical storing devices (hard drives). I bet the problem is 40 or even 50 years old; the lag was more substantial then because the storage devices at that time were magnetic tapes. The problem can be solved with a single pass on the input file (and multiple partial passed on the output file).

Comment: Ok, I assumed the problem was "modern"... :)  So I am curious to know the "right" solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: this answer **does not** use a constant number of repositioning in the output file.

---

This is a solution inspired by @Renzo's answer. In fact, it is a simplified version of that answer.

Using the same notations, let's say the input file is `F1` and its size is `B * M` where `B` is the size of two buffers (`b1` and `b2`) we have in memory and `F2` is the output file.

The idea is simple: read a block of `B` bytes into buffer `b1`, flip its bits into `b2` (can also flip them in place, if you like it more this way), write data from buffer `b2` into `F2` as many times it needs until it gets written in its final position in `F2`. Rewind `F2` and repeat until all the blocks from `F1` are processed. On each iteration, the content of buffer `b2` is written to `F2` one time less than on the previous iteration.

#### The (pseudo-)code

```
// Open the files
fopen(F1);
fopen(F2);

// Process the input in blocks of size B
for (i = 0; i < M; i ++) {
    // Read the next block of B bytes from F1 into b1
    fread(b1, B, F1);
    // Flip the bits from b1 into b2
    flip_the_bits(b1, b2);
    // Rewind F2, write b2 in it several times
    rewind(F2);
    // Write b2 in F2 once for each block not written yet
    // This overwrites the blocks written on the previous iteration
    // except for the last one
    for (j = i; j < M; j ++) {
        fwrite(b2, B, 1, F2);
    }
}
// Close the files
fclose(F1);
fclose(F2);
```

#### Remarks about the code

If the file size is not a multiple of `B` then `M` is rounded up to the nearest integer and the iteration when `i == 0` and `j == M-1` must take care to write only the needed bytes into the output file (only the tail of the `b2` buffer).

There is no positioning in the input file (it is open, read head-to-tail and closed) but there are a lot of rewinds (`M`) on the output file and also a lot of data is rewritten. There are `M*(M+1)/2` writes for `M` useful blocks of data. Rewinding is a repositioning.

In the extreme case when `B == 1` and `M == filesize(F1)` the code has maximum efficiency on the used memory (two bytes for the two buffers or a single byte if the flip is done in place) but the worst performance on time (positioning and writes). More memory (as much as possible) makes it run as fast as possible.

#### A little history

The problem is probably 40 or 50 years old. The storage devices at that time were magnetic tapes and repositioning on magnetic tapes takes time. This is why the problem asks to use as few repositioning as possible. And this is why the `C` function that positions the pointer at the beginning of the file is named [*`rewind()`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind).

As @Joachim notes in a comment on the question, we need to use `fseek()` once to go to the end of the file to find its size and another one to go back to the beginning of the file and start processing it.

Maybe this was the way to go back then when the magnetic tapes were the cutting edge storage technology, I don't know. The modern operating systems provide functions to find the size of a file without needing to `fseek()` to its end and back.

Comment: But `rewind` is also a re positioning function.

Comment: Indeed, my answer does not follow the constraint of using a constant number of seeks.

Comment: Upvoted since it is an improvement over my algorithm! But, are you sure that a solution actually *exists*? BTW, did you have some reference to the original problem?

Comment: Ok, I have now a proof that such solution does not exists, but unfortunately it is so big that does not fit into the space of a StackOverflow comment! :-)

Comment: @Renzo post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some obscure nonstandard function to reverse the direction in which the file pointer advances, I see no way around of reading the whole thing into a large buffer and go from there.

Now in case you're not limited to use stdio and are running on a system with large address space (something with more than, say 48 bits, like any modern 64 bit architecture) you could use a *memory mapping* instead of reading into a buffer. Actually a better name would be *address space mapping* (but memory map is what stuck): Instead of reading the file into a large chunk of allocated memory, you can as well tell the operating system: "Okay, here I've got this file, and I want its contents to appear in the process' address space". The OS will do it, and accessing such an address space location will actually read from the file in-situ (no intermediary buffer involved). A file memory map can also be used for writing.

See `mmap` for POSIX systems and `CreateFileMapping`+`MapViewOfFile` for Windows.

I don't know if that would be considered cheating though. Also I'm eager to see the official solution.